# Difference in complexity of append and concatenate for this list code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, big-o, time-complexity

Consider below methods for forming a list of thousand numbers.

```
def test1():
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        l = l + [i]
    return l


def test2():
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        l.append(i)    

print timeit.repeat(stmt=test1, number=100,repeat=2)
print timeit.repeat(stmt=test2, number=100,repeat=2)
```

Output:

```
[0.30474191033602543, 0.3783786557587963]
[0.015134341605235302, 0.023081246200096328]
```

Why is the append method around 20 times better than concatenation. AFAIK append has O(1) complexity while concatenation has O(k) complexity. While K here is 1.

Is there some obvious thing I overlooked?

Comment: Due to the mistake in the code, this question is not as general as the original title ("...for lists") would suggest, and thus it should not be canonical.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are creating a *new* list object each time by concatenating. This requires copying all elements from the old list into a new one, plus one extra. So yes, using `l = l + [i]` is an O(N) algorithm, not O(1).

At the very least, don't use `+` concatenation; use `+=` *augmented* concatenation, which is the same thing as `list.extend()` with a re-assignment to the same reference:

```
def test3():
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        l += [i]  # or use l.extend([i])
    return l
```

This produces:

```
>>> print timeit.repeat(stmt=test1, number=100, repeat=2)
[0.1333179473876953, 0.12804388999938965]
>>> print timeit.repeat(stmt=test2, number=100, repeat=2)
[0.01052403450012207, 0.007989168167114258]
>>> print timeit.repeat(stmt=test3, number=100, repeat=2)
[0.013209104537963867, 0.011193037033081055]
```

Comment: still it's taking `[0.047872320772834216, 0.04017255103519537]` about 2 times than append.

Comment: @garg10may: no, it's not. See my timings.

Comment: @garg10may: and O(1) is a *class* of performance, not a precise measurement; the constant time between different O(1) algorithms can still vary.

Comment: but not to be pedantic, still append will always be better than augmented concatenation. I would agree if sometimes it would show lower timings.

Comment: @garg10may: `list.append()` is absolutely the best approach for adding a single element, no doubt about it.

Comment: Any reason why it should be better, when `+=` also changes the same object.

Comment: @garg10may: `+=` has to do more work; it has to resize the existing object by a variable number of elements, so there is a loop involved. `.append()` knows there is always 1 element more to be added, simplifying the logic.