# Run time of flattening a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, tree

For a simple algorithm that flattens a binary tree given this structure:

```
class Tree(object):
   def __init__(self, x):
     self.value = x
     self.left = None
     self.right = None
```

What would the run time be for this algorithm that flattens a binary tree into an array?

```
def flatten(root):
    if root == None:
        return []
    return flatten(root.left) + [root.value] + flatten(root.right)
```

I am thinking it's `N` time, `2N` space complexity because the algorithm is going from the root and then out to the left and the right nodes.

I think it's `2N` space complexity because you still have the N space the tree is occupying and `N` space from the resulting array.

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: BTW `O(2N)` is just the same a `O(N)`. Space complexity is usually just a measure of the working storage (not your starting and ending data structures), which is just the call stack for the depth of your tree assuming a balanced tree space complexity would be `O(log N)` (worst-case `O(N)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the running time for an in-order traversal of a binary tree is O(N), because you visit each node in the tree exactly once. However, your code is concatenating arrays which, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33191492/56778, is an O(N) operation. If that's true, which it appears to be, then the running time of your code will be O(N^2).

When talking about space complexity, we normally talk about *extra* space: space that is in addition to the space already taken up by the data structure. Sometimes they don't include the space for the output array.

In your case, it takes O(N) space for the new array, plus O(log N) space for the recursion stack, *provided the tree is balanced*. If the tree is unbalanced, it could require up to O(N) extra space for the recursion stack.

So the extra space is O(N) + O(N) if the tree is unbalanced, or O(N) + O(log N) if the tree is balanced. Either way, it's considered O(N) extra space.

Comment: Your O(N) running time classification assumes that concatenating arrays is a constant-time operation, independent of the array sizes. I'm not a python expert, but e.g. in Java array concatenation is linear-time.